# What kind of algorithm makes a curve like this (img) & can it be done in javascript for flot?

Tags: javascript, math, flot

And can you give me an example of an algorithm?
[alt text http://ryancalderoni.com/archive/ideal_curve.jpg](http://ryancalderoni.com/archive/ideal_curve.jpg)

EDIT: And then how would I calculate the math using Javascript? Can someone add that? Sorry to not include that context originally..

NOTE: I am using 'flot' to graph it and the input for flot is a javascript array like this:

[[x,y],[x,y],[x,y]...]

So given the values that change the curve I output all the points to an array with a loop and spit it out to flot to graph.

Comment: better off on math.stackexchange? EDIT: Didn't know there was two.

Comment: You might want to try asking at http://math.stackexchange.com/.  StackOverflow is meant for programming-related questions.

Comment: @James: No. Definitely not. Math Overflow is for research-level math questions, not for things an undergrad might ponder (mostly, at least). Please stop recommending that one for every math question you see here because it's usually severely out of scope there.

Comment: There should be a way to vote something to mathoverflow, the same way you can do it for SU or meta SO or Serverfault

Comment: here I'll make an edit to include the programming details because that is the context I am using this in

Comment: @Frustrated - MathOverflow is an SE 1.0 site and as such there isn't (nor will there ever be) a migration route. If MathOverflow ever migrates to SE 2.0 there may well be a migration route, but as @Johannes points out this question would be off topic there and would get instantly closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A typical sigmoid curve is the tanh(x) curve.

By definition,

```
  tanh(x) = sinh(x) / cosh(x) =
          = [(1/2) (e^x - e^-x)] / [(1/2) (e^x + e^-x)] =
          = (e^x - e^-x) / (e^x + e^-x) = 
          = (e^(2x) - 1) / (e^(2x) + 1)
```

[image]
[(High-res)](https://privat.rejbrand.se/tanh.png)

Notice that the lines of symmetry are shifted with respect to your sample picture. To make a tanh graph look more like your example, simply move it up and to the right:

```
y = 1 + (e^(2x - 6) - 1) / (e^(2x - 6) + 1)
```

[image]
[(High-res)](https://privat.rejbrand.se/tanh2.png)

In JavaScript you implement this expression most efficiently as

```
exp2x = Math.exp(2*x)
y = (exp2x - 1) / (exp2x + 1)
```

## Update (again)

OK, if you want y to range from 0 to 100, and x to range from 0 to 100, than you might want to try

```
y = 50 + 50*tanh((x−50)/10)
```

which looks like

[image]
[(High-res)](https://privat.rejbrand.se/tanh3.png)

Now

```
y = 50 + 50 * tanh((x−50)/10)
  = 50 + 50 * (e^((x−50)/5) - 1) / (e^((x−50)/5) + 1)
```

The error function, erf, looks quite similar, but is *much* more difficult to compute (unless JavaScript has a built-in erf function).

---

Ryan (OP) adds: **implemented!**

```
var y = 50 + 50 * tanh((n-50)/10);

function tanh (arg) {
    return (Math.exp(arg) - Math.exp(-arg)) / (Math.exp(arg) + Math.exp(-arg));
}
```

Comment: thanks but my implementation isn't working as I'd expect, for every X value I add it returns the same Y value (a straight line is coming out)

Comment: @Ryan: That might be because you forget to update exp2x each time. The expression is really `y = (Math.exp(2*x)- 1) / (Math.exp(2*x)+ 1`. I just optimized a bit by reducing one of the identical calls to the slow `exp` function.

Comment: see added details, +1 for your help so far, one step closer to the answer vote :)

Comment: The tanh function makes a good sigmoid shape on x \in [-3, 3], say. Very close to x ~ 0, tanh does look like the straight line y = x. See this picture: http://privat.rejbrand.se/tanh.png

Comment: OK cool I see your update for shifting the curve, still working on getting it to draw right, and obviously give me the values I want (Y axis represents a percentage in my use case so must be between 0-100)

Comment: Yes, I see the problem. Well, as I said, the graph y = tanh(x) has the desired shape if you look at x between -3 and 3 (say). For x > 3, the graph becomes increasingly linear (and planar). So you are plotting the function in the wrong domain! Plot it in x = -3 to x = +3 instead. Or, shift the graph.

Comment: Thanks Andreas, can you show me how to shift it in javascript too? I think I am doing it wrong: return 1 + (Math.pow(exp2x, ((2*x) - 6)) - 1) / (Math.pow(exp2x, ((2*x) - 6)) +1);

Comment: I see your update for the 0-100 range THANKS, now I just gotta get it into my JS properly, I've awarded you the answer of course :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want a single, analytic function, then ArcTangent and Hyperbolic Tangent both have that shape, you just need to shift it over a bit. If you want it to only start at the origin and be flat, look at Exp[-1/x^n], for n>=1. This produces a curve that is exceedingly flat at the origin.

Comment: updated the question to show programming relation, any idea how to put this algorithm in javascript?

Answer (score 2):

Try to lookup sigmoid function, it looks a lot like it.

[image]
<sub>(source: [iag at ulcar.uml.edu](http://ulcar.uml.edu/~iag/CS/Sigmoid-function.GIF))</sub>

Comment: It doesn't just look like a sigmoid function, it *is* a sigmoid function. Which, exactly, I cannot say. Btw: Your "URL" is invalid.

Comment: @Andreas, your comment makes me think were you able to figure out how to view this... ??

Comment: @Ryan: The mess in Jesper's message do include a valid link: http://ulcar.uml.edu/~iag/CS/Sigmoid-function.GIF

Comment: when you write an answer, you have a real-time preview just below the input window

Comment: fixed the link for you Jesper, and +1 after the repairs to cancel the -1 since this actually is one that could possibly work for me, thanks

Comment: mykhal: The instant preview worked, while it didn't show up here – this is the perpetual problem of implementations with different bugs and behavior; there's a lot more different between the preview and the final result here. Andreas: The URI Ryan gave was a valid one – that doesn't stop a faulty URI parser to mess things up.

Comment: The reason the image didn't show up in the first place is that you need 15 rep to be able to post images. Can't find the reference right now though.

Answer (score 1):

A [Bézier curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve)? The corresponding algorithm to draw it would be [de Casteljau's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Casteljau%27s_algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

Might I sugggest:

- The error function (`erf(x)` in C)
- The normal cumulative distribution function (`0.5 * erfc(-x/sqrt(2))`)
- The logistic function (`1.0 / (1.0 + exp(-x))`)
- Any other sigmoid function

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called Sigmoid function. You can look it up in Wikipedia. Some function that are used for this are error function or logistic function. These are most commonly use for neural networks.

Answer (score 0):

All this is wonderful, but there's another thought:

Assume a third order polynomial:

[image]
<sub>(source: [equationsheet.com](http://www.equationsheet.com/latexrender/pictures/8d042b424361b16bfd1c090dd1fc79a8.gif))</sub>

You have four boundary conditions:

[image]

[image]
<sub>(source: [equationsheet.com](http://www.equationsheet.com/latexrender/pictures/92ceaf735e53c4afdf27a03bc87ae061.gif))</sub>

[image]

[image]
<sub>(source: [equationsheet.com](http://www.equationsheet.com/latexrender/pictures/a785bd3b5739f5ca9ae107f5ee6f3de9.gif))</sub>

If you substitute these into the equation and work out the algebra you get the following result:

[image]
<sub>(source: [equationsheet.com](http://www.equationsheet.com/latexrender/pictures/d418a85eb8a1496e585401bf8fb87325.gif))</sub>

where

[image]
<sub>(source: [equationsheet.com](http://www.equationsheet.com/latexrender/pictures/beb02d38c3481bd50aead656ecfafe83.gif))</sub>

and

[image]
<sub>(source: [equationsheet.com](http://www.equationsheet.com/latexrender/pictures/f912827654a96fc5cc8e66c79123e653.gif))</sub>

It may not be exact, but you can easily approximate it based on the values you know: [image]
<sub>(source: [equationsheet.com](http://www.equationsheet.com/latexrender/pictures/2e3b3b42bd7570d517e5b20bab76a9b6.gif))</sub>